# View not updating till orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Currently I have an app that allows a user to look at a request and add notes or images to the request.  Everything looks good, but I don't want to have to recreate the activity to show the updated information.  I have the note portion working fine, but the image portion doesn't update until the configuration changes on orientation change.

Is is the post execute that uses the displayThumbnails function to recreate the imageviews.

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
         if (errorMessage.equals("")) {
            updateImageProgress.dismiss();
            isupdateImageProgressShowing = false;
            displayThumbnails(updatedThumbPaths);
```

This is the actual function call to recreate the imageviews.

```
    private void displayThumbnails(String[] path) {
    thumbnails.removeAllViews();
    thumbnails.invalidate();
    if (imageCount > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < imageCount; i++) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path[i]);
            Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 150, 150,
                    false);
            bitmap.recycle();
            ImageView imgPhoto = new ImageView(this.getActivity());
            imgPhoto.setImageBitmap(scaled);
            imgPhoto.setId(i);
            imgPhoto.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            imgPhoto.setClickable(true);
            if(updatedThumbPaths == null){
                imgPhoto.setOnClickListener(photoPopup);
            }else{
                imgPhoto.setOnClickListener(updatePhotoPopup);
            }
            thumbnails.addView(imgPhoto);
        }
    }

}
```

So does anyone have any suggestion on how to redraw the imageviews without having to recreate the entire fragment/activity.

Comment: Are you using `ASyncTask`? If so, show the code for that and show how you call the ASyncTask also.

Comment: I am using an async task.  The task goes and checks the server for images and downloads them if they are not already stored locally.  The image names and id's are stored in a database.  After that it goes to the onPostExecute as shown above.  The displayThumbnails function then removes all the views and should use the images paths to create new views.  The AsyncTask is called as follows.  new GetImages().execute();

Comment: Do you call the `GetImages().execute();` again after the user "add notes or images to the request"? Otherwise the `postExecute()` method will not be called.

Comment: The GetImages().execute(); was not called again and onPostExecute was being called.  The problem came down to a counter in a for loop.